CSS Flex: Order 1st element at the end of 1st row
I'd like to do either of these options:

I'm using a flex-wrap: wrap container to display a bunch of items of equal size. Except the 1st item, which is larger than the rest.
I'm able to vertically bottom-align the 1st item with the rest of its row using align-items: end. But I'd like to also horizontally align the 1st row with the below rows. If I use margin-right: auto on the 1st element, it pushes the rest of the 1st row too far to the right. I'd like to not hardcode a margin value, since the exact width of the elements is a messy computation with padding and borders, e.g. 360.831.


.container {
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: end;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container div {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.container div:nth-child(even) {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.container .large {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  /* float: right; float doesn't work in flex */
  /* margin-right: auto; pushes the rest of the row too the edge of the container */
  /* margin-right: 29.53400px; requires JS to figure out the exact computed border thickness */
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="large"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>




all the element size (except the container) are known/fixed ?

@TemaniAfif yes, all except the container have fixed and known sizes. But because they have borders, their total width including borders ends up being a decimal value; e.g. 54.53 for the small boxes in this example. I don't want to hard code 54.53 anywhere in the css. But I'm fine hardcoding 50 and 75.

Have you considered using grid instead?

@AHaworth I'm looking into it - forgot they existed until after I posted the question.

Doable using CSS grid


.container {
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 50px);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  align-items: end;
  align-content: end;
  justify-content: start;
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
}
.container div {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
.container div:nth-child(even) {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
.container .large {
  grid-column: span 2;
  /* or 
   grid-column: span 2/-1 
   margin-left: auto;
  */
  width: 75px; /* if this value doesn't fit inside 2 cells, use 3 cells */
  
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="large"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>



